# Access a composition field of a struct from Trait

Tags: rust, traits, composition

In the following example, is there any way to access the comp_field within the implementation of BaseTrait for MyStruct?

```
pub trait CompositionTrait {
    //methods
}

pub trait BaseTrait {
    fn get_comp_field(&self) -> Box<dyn CompositionTrait>;
}

pub struct MyStruct {
    pub comp_field: Box<dyn CompositionTrait>
}

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn new(config: Config) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        // here based on config, comp_field is assigned with different structs, all of which implements CompositionTrait.
    }
}

impl BaseTrait for MyStruct {
    fn get_comp_field(&self) -> Box<dyn CompositionTrait> {
        self.comp_field // Error
    }
}
```

The following error is presented for the current implementation:

```
cannot move out of `self.comp_field` which is behind a shared reference

move occurs because `self.comp_field` has type `std::boxed::Box<dyn BaseTrait::CompositionTrait>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

The eventual need for such implementation would be accessing the methods of comp_field in the functions which are based on BaseTrait.

Comment: Do you really need to move the box out of the struct? You probably should use `fn get_comp_field(&self) -> &dyn CompositionTrait { &self.comp_field }` instead.

Comment: No, I just need to have an accessor to _comp_field_. By applying your suggestion, compiler complains `the trait CompositionTrait is not implemented for Box<(dyn CompositionTrait + 'static)>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because you're trying to move the box out of the struct, but the struct is not mutable (and even if it was you would need to put something else in place of the box you're removing). Instead you should return a reference to the `CompositionTrait`:

```
pub trait CompositionTrait {
    //methods
}

pub trait BaseTrait {
    fn get_comp_field(&self) -> &dyn CompositionTrait;
}

pub struct MyStruct {
    pub comp_field: Box<dyn CompositionTrait>
}

impl BaseTrait for MyStruct {
    fn get_comp_field(&self) -> &dyn CompositionTrait {
        &*self.comp_field // Or self.comp_field.as_ref()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2daa6fa4d7fcb2205cdf9da227b1151c)